# Stability of the structure made of magnets

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, stability

From 4 magnets and 3 steel screwdrivers we can create a fairly stable structure, see the picture on the left. This structure is made on a rotating table, so it can be rotated around a vertical axis. With this rotation, stability is maintained. Let's leave this structure for a long time and see what happens. A structure can survive for a day or two, and then suddenly collapses, forming a new structure (see the picture on the right). The question arises, what is the reason for the destruction of this structure?
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I think that the flat magnetic surface on the small screwdriver diameter has a very small friction surface. Under vibration, the magnet and the screwdriver hanging over it will slowly slide downwards.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler This is a good idea that comes to mind first. But two days is a long time. Are there any other reasons? For example, a magnetic storm.

Comment: Good point. Take it into the fridg.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Do you mean to make a protective screen? As is known, a magnetic storm can affect the operation of various devices. It would be interesting to evaluate whether a magnetic storm could affect the stability of such structures.